# beautify url from art.php?id=51 to art/51

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lightspeed

want to beautify an url from:
`https://abuena.net/art.php?id=51`
to
`https://abuena.net/art/51`

here is my try, without success, simply is ignored

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /art.php?id=$1
```

My hosting provider says that my server is not Apache but LSWS - LiteSpeed WebServer - and that is probably problem in my syntax.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Considering that you need to hit URLs like `https://abuena.net/art/51` in your browser. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case you are hitting URL like `https://abuena.net/art.php?id=51` in your browser then try following once.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \s/([^.]*)\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```